# python WMI : How to see running process on main screen

Tags: python, wmi

I am using python wmi to run some my script on the remote machine. The script open a browser and do some operation. I am able to run the process on the remote machine without any error but I can't see the browser on the screen of the remote node. Is there a way in which I can bring the process to the main screen of the remote machine? Here is my code

```
import wmi,time

SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1

c = wmi.WMI("192.168.1.5", user="domain\myuser", password="mypassword")
process_startup = c.Win32_ProcessStartup.new()
process_startup.ShowWindow = SW_SHOWNORMAL

process_id, result = c.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine="C:/Users/myUser/my.bat ", ProcessStartupInformation=process_startup)

if result == 0:
    print "Process started successfully: %d" % process_id
else:
    raise RuntimeError, "Problem creating process: %d" % result

watcher = c.watch_for (notification_type="Deletion", wmi_class="Win32_Process", delay_secs=1, ProcessId=process_id)
watcher()
print "Sionara"
```

Comment: If you are logged in as myuser on that machine and my.bat does what it should, you should see whatever program you are trying to start. Do note however that if the execution of whatever is in my.bat fails, there will be no problem in creating the process and your test will pass but your result will not be as expected. Suggest having my.bat log the result of each action it does in a separate logfile you can consult after run.

Comment: Hi @BoboDarph, This is not any urgent need. It's just that I wanted screen to be interactive in need. Please share if you know the way.

Comment: Just log in as the test user on the remote machine and run your test. If your batch file does what it's supposed to do and if that thing causes programs to start on the screen, they will be displayed. If your batch file starts programs in the background, then no, you won't see anything on the remote machine.